# C++ - Cannot See Created Mutex Using WinObj

Tags: c++, winapi, mutex

I am using this really simple code to try to create a mutex

```
int main(){
    
    HANDLE hMutex = ::CreateMutex(nullptr, FALSE, L"SingleInstanceMutex");
    if(!hMutex){
        
        wchar_t buff[1000];

        _snwprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), L"Failed to create mutex (Error: %d)", ::GetLastError());   
         
        ::MessageBox(nullptr, buff, L"Single Instance", MB_OK);


        return 0x1;
    } else {
        ::MessageBox(nullptr, L"Mutex Created", L"Single Instance", MB_OK);
    }
    
    return 0x0;
}
```

And I get the message "Mutex Created" like if it is correctly created, but when I try to search it using the tool WinObj of SysInternals I can't find it.

Also if I restart the program many times while another instance is running I always get the message "Mutex Created" and never an error because the mutex already exists.

I'm trying it on a Windows 7 VM.

What I'm doing wrong?

Ah I'm compiling on Linux using:

```
i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ Mutex.cpp
```

Thank you!

Comment: The mutex gets destroyed as the system cleans up during process termination. You're either looking after the process has terminated, or you're looking in the wrong place (global vs. session-local).

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer, actually I'm searching for the mutex name inside all folders of WinObj (I'm using the search function on the toolbar) and I'm leaving the program that generate the mutex running.
How can I know if the mutex is getting destroyed or similar? Shouldn't it be destroyed after the program that generated it exists? Thank you

Comment: `CreateMutex` is not locking the mutex, only giving you a handle to the kernel object. In the case of a named mutex like yours, all processes should succeed to get the handle. You need to use `ReleaseMutex` and `WaitForSingleObject` to unlock/lock it. If you'll do that you'll observe that only one process can lock the mutex.

Comment: @Davide on a side note: have you considered using `std::wostringstream` or `std::format()` instead of `snprintf()`? The way you convert `std::string` to `std::wstring` won't work for non-ASCII characters. If you want to use a fixed character buffer, why not start with `wchar_t[]` to begin with and use `_snwprintf()` instead?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you for your advice. But I tried to use "std::format()" but I didn't find a way to make it work. I mean I cannot include the <format> header and on compile time it says that format is not a member of std. I edited my question with a change, is that what you meant that I should do by using wchar_t[]? Thank you!

Comment: @Davide are you using C++20? If not, there is [{fmt}](https://fmt.dev/latest/index.html) for earlier versions. In any case, yes, that is what I meant with `wchar_t[]`

Comment: "*I always get the message "Mutex Created" and never an error because the mutex already exists.*" - if a named mutex already exists, `CreateMutex()` returns a non-null handle to it. You have to consult `GetLastError()` to differentiate between "newly created" and "already existed".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use a **Windows mutex** (whether a *named* one like yours or an *unnamed* one), you need to use the following Win APIs:

1. [**`CreateMutex`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-createmutexw)  - to obtain a handle to the mutex [**Windows kernel object**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/kernel-objects). In case of a named mutex (like yours) multiple processes should succeed to get this handle. The first one will cause the OS to create a new named mutex, and the others will get a handle referring to that same mutex.
   In case the function succeeds and you get a valid handle to the named mutex, you can determine whether the mutex already existed (i.e. that another process already created the mutex) by checking if [`GetLastError`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror) returns **`ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`**.
2. [**`WaitForSingleObject`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitforsingleobject) - to lock the mutex for exclusive access. This function is actually not specific to mutex and is used for many kernel objects. See the link above for more info about Windows kernel objects.
3. [**`ReleaseMutex`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-releasemutex) - to unlock the mutex.
4. [**`CloseHandle`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/handleapi/nf-handleapi-closehandle) - to release the acquired mutex handle (as usual with Windows handles). The OS will automatically close the handle when the process exists, but it is good practice to do it explicitly.

**A complete example:**

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    // Create the mutex handle:
    HANDLE hMutex = ::CreateMutex(nullptr, FALSE, L"SingleInstanceMutex");
    if (!hMutex)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create mutex handle." << std::endl;
        // Handle error: ...
        return 1;
    }
    bool bAlreadyExisted = (GetLastError() == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS);
    std::cout << "Succeeded to create mutex handle. Already existed: " << (bAlreadyExisted ? "YES" : "NO") << std::endl;

    // Lock the mutex:
    std::cout << "Atempting to lock ..." << std::endl;
    DWORD dwRes = ::WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, INFINITE);
    if (dwRes != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to lock the mutex" << std::endl;
        // Handle error: ...
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout << "Locked." << std::endl;

    // Do something that required the lock: ...
    std::cout << "Press ENTER to unlock." << std::endl;
    std::getchar();

    // Unlock the mutex:
    if (!::ReleaseMutex(hMutex))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to unlock the mutex" << std::endl;
        // Handle error: ...
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout << "Unlocked." << std::endl;

    // Free the handle:
    if (!CloseHandle(hMutex))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to close the mutex handle" << std::endl;
        // Handle error: ...
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Error handling:**
As you can see in the documentation links above, when `CreateMutex`,`ReleaseMutex` and `CloseHandle` fail, you should call [**`GetLastError`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror) to get more info about the error. `WaitForSingleObject` will return a specific return value upon error (see the documentation link above). This should be done as a part of the `// Handle error: ...` sections.

**Note:**
Using a named mutex for IPC (interprocess communication) might be the only good use case for native Windows mutexes.
For a regular unnamed mutex it's better to use one of the available standard library types of mutexes: [`std::mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex),[`std::recursive_mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/recursive_mutex),[`std::recursive_timed_mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/recursive_timed_mutex) (the last 2 support repeated lock by a thread, similarly to Windows mutex).

Comment: Hello thank you for you answer, I tryed the code but I can't still see the mutex inside WinObj. Is that normal?

Comment: @Davide I am not familiar with WinObj. But do you observe the mutual execlusion effect ? (i.e. that while the 1st process keeps the mutex locked, the 2nd process is kept outside the relevant code).

Comment: No ok I found it I was using WinObj instead of WinObj64

Comment: Yes it is mutual exclusion on thanks (:

Comment: It would help if you explained the specific case more thoroughly, i.e. how to determine whether `CreateMutex` created a new mutex or returned a reference to an existing one. As for valid use cases, a Windows-native mutex has properties different from `std::mutex`, namely, that a thread owning a mutex can repeatedly wait on it. A [`std::recursive_timed_mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/recursive_timed_mutex) would be a far closer match. Though you should probably use an [SRW Lock](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/slim-reader-writer--srw--locks) instead anyway.

Comment: @IInspectable thanks. Updated based on your comment. Regarding SRW_Lock - in general I prefer not to advocate the usage of OS specfic mechanisms, when there are proper standard ones. Having said that I understand that OS specific stuff might offer some advatages that might be relevant in certain specific cases.

Comment: The update is still missing a vital piece of information: When `CreateMutex` returns a non-zero value you must call `GetLastError` to learn what actually happened.

Comment: Added a clarification about using `GetLastError` when a relavant API fail.

Comment: The clarification didn't. You will want to call `GetLastError` when `CreateMutex` **succeeds**.

Comment: @IInspectable now I understand what you meant - thanks! I was not aware of the option to use GetLastError to identify whether the mutex already existed (used it only for cases of  failure). I should have read the documentation link I posed till the end ... Updated my answer again (and demonstrated in the code).